# break from the while loop

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I wrote a simple dice game, that works as intended except the part I'm struggling with, which is how to end the game with the specific key pressed. I know I'm doing simple mistake (well I'm a beginner), but if you could just point out what's wrong with the code, I'll be glad.

Thanks!

```
import random



def game():
    while True:

        userRoll = int(raw_input("Enter a number from 1 to 10 [press q to end the game]: "))
        compRoll = random.randrange(1, 11)

        print "You rolled " + str(userRoll) 
        print "Computer rolled " + str(compRoll)

        if userRoll > compRoll and userRoll > 0 and userRoll < 11:
            print "You win!"

        elif userRoll == compRoll:
            print "It's a tie!"

        elif userRoll < compRoll:
            print "Computer wins!"

        elif userRoll == 'q':
            print "bye"
            break

        else:
            print "You must enter number from 1 to 10. Try again..."

game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not useful:

```
    elif userRoll == 'q':
        print "bye"
        break
```

By the time that that code executes, you have already converted `userRoll` to an integer.  So, if can never by `q`.
The following code tests `userRoll == 'q'` before the conversion to integer:

```
import random

def game():
    while True:

        userRoll = raw_input("Enter a number from 1 to 10 [press q to end the game]: ")
        if userRoll == 'q':
            print "bye"
            break
        userRoll = int(userRoll)

        compRoll = random.randrange(1, 11)

        print "You rolled " + str(userRoll)_
        print "Computer rolled " + str(compRoll)

        if userRoll > compRoll and userRoll > 0 and userRoll < 11:
            print "You win!"

        elif userRoll == compRoll:
            print "It's a tie!"

        elif userRoll < compRoll:
            print "Computer wins!"

        else:
            print "You must enter number from 1 to 10. Try again..."

game()
```

Comment: Thanks!. How could I forget it.